# Как в TypeScript указать массив классов?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Например у меня есть класс Module и от него будут наследовать много классов. Например модуль User или модуль Session, и я хочу хранить все эти классы в одном месте.

```
class User extends Module {

}

api.addModule(User)
```

как мне описать тип аргумента принимаемый функцией addModule?

```
addModule (moduleClass:Function){
  this.modules[moduleClass.name] = moduleClass
}
```

moduleClass:Function??? фанкшен работает, но мне нужны не любые функции а именно классы, да еще и унаследованные от Module

более того я хочу создать функцию addModules

```
api.addModules([User, Session])
```

чтобы можно было принимать массив классов =)
подскажите как такой параметр описать в тайпскрипте? чтобы как бы не инстанс класса, а именно сам класс или его классы наследники.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

для указания того, что нам нужен не инстанс класса, а сам класс, применяется конструкция: `typeof Class`

```
addModule(ModuleClass:typeof Module) {
    this.modules[module.name] = ModuleClass
}

getModule(name:string):typeof Module {
    return this.modules[name]
}

addModules(modules:typeof Module[]) {

}
```

моя ошибка заключалась в том что я использовал устаревший синтаксис типа typeof(Module) который я нагуглил в обсуждении разработчиков тайпскрипта которое они вели аж в 2012 году ^_^